# How can i make unit test cases of Login screen in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, unit-testing

I am having an issue on the logIn screen. how can I make a unit test case with a login screen? I have username and password screen with an action button. I need to call an API when clicking on a button and make some unit test cases. Please provide me some information. thanks in advance.

Comment: I would advise you to Mock your network requests so that you can control the expected response consistently and then test that the correct actions are done

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to structure your code so that it doesn't actually initiate the login API call. Instead, it:

- Creates the request, but stops before sending it
- Handles the response

Then you can test that filling in the fields and tapping the button creates the correct request. After that, you can test various responses, including all sort of error cases that are hard to create in end-to-end testing.

To tap a button from a unit test, make it so that the test can access the button. Then call `sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)`

---

Example: There are many ways to structure this. Let's say we have a protocol

```
protocol NetworkCalling {
    typealias CallResult = Result<(Data, URLResponse), Error>
    typealias CompletionHandler = (CallResult) -> Void

    func call(request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping CompletionHandler)
}
```

Our view controller will use whatever it's given. It doesn't care. It just knows how to make a URLRequest from its properties. It also knows how to handle the result, for both success and failure.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var networkCall: NetworkCalling?
    
    @IBAction private func login(sender: AnyObject) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://foo.bar?baz")!)
        networkCall?.call(request: request) { [weak self] result in
            self?.handleResult(result)
        }
    }

    private func handleResult(_ result: NetworkCalling.CallResult) {
        switch result {
        case let .success(data, response):
            break
        case let .failure(error):
            break
        }
    }
}
```

The protocol introduces a boundary. The view controller can't see past that boundary. It's not the view controller's business. The protocol gives us opportunities to provide different implementers:

- Something that makes real network calls.
- A Decorator that wraps another implementer, doing logging.
- A Test Spy that captures its arguments for unit testing.
- A fake that replays stored responses for UI testing. This makes UI tests faster and more reliable.

Comment: Can you please share an example for the login screen.

Comment: Added an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can write multiple test cases by sending different parameters for Username and Password.

Wrong usernames and passwords should give you error message and then you can check if you are receiving the error message instead of success message.

Entering right username and password should give you success messages as response.

Use XCTAssertEqual to compare messages.

There could be better UITest cases on this screen.

Comment: can you share any example @Huned

Answer (score 0):

Although the question seems to be kind of broad, let me mention some of the useful points:

- In unit test, we care about the *functionality* of the scene instead of caring about visual UI components -for example-. So, what are you saying about testing about login:

> I need to call an API when clicking on a button and make some unit
>   test cases.

is valid, it is one of the main functionality in the scene.

- You should focus on testing *your code*, but *not* the API itself. In other words, your test cases should be implemented in a way that you expect a certain response (such as success or fail), therefore what should happen when receiving it, it means that do not try to test the API response itself (we are not doing integration tests here), you should care about what your code behaves based on the response.
- Regarding to the above point, how to apply it? You could follow the approach of "mocking" the response. Briefly, what you could do is to create mock class that contains the same behaviors for the used network manager thus you can hard-code the received results (assumptions) as -for instance- success of failure thus testing what should happen for the received "mocked" result.