# How to write test case for Login screen ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, swift5, xctest

I want to create test cases for Login screen my screen contains three text field for username, password and url and one "LOGIN "button which calls login API, after login success Home screen opens. I want to create test cases for text fields and login button event. Need example to start test cases.
I am new in swift, your help will be appreciated. 
Thanks,

Comment: Is it duplicated? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55949509/how-can-i-make-unit-test-cases-of-login-screen-in-ios-swift

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i make unit test cases of Login screen in iOS swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55949509/how-can-i-make-unit-test-cases-of-login-screen-in-ios-swift)

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to Swift & XCTest, I would suggest reading some articles about it first.

E.g. these:

[Getting started with Xcode UI testing in Swift](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/getting-started-with-xcode-ui-testing-in-swift/)

[Guide to advanced UI tests on iOS](https://code.kiwi.com/guide-to-advanced-ui-tests-on-ios-8950355d2649)

If you then need test cases for such screen - you have to evaluate your screen usage and importance of its features. Being able to log in is probably the most important function of them all, so I would start with these test cases - logging in with valid credentials, with invalid credentials, with incomplete credentials etc. and expecting correct results to occur. After that, I would focus on the screen usability - that it's not refreshing and losing textfield focus, that the password is not visible and so on.

Number and focus of test cases is up to you really.